# Faster way to execute this sql query with php

Tags: php, sql

i am using this query

```
$query = "SELECT SQL_CACHE * FROM `like` WHERE `id` ='$id' LIMIT 0 , 1";        
$result = @mysql_query ($query); // Run the query.
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$crap= $row['crap'];
```

is there any faster way to execute this query?
i want to execute this as fast as possible
i am using php
thanks

Comment: this is already in its optimal state....

Comment: @AlphaMale: No its not - there is a ptential benefit from only selecting the columns which are subsequently used, and we don't know if there is an index on like.id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have an index in place on the `id` column? That's the only way I can think to speed things up.

And maybe selecting only the `crap` column specifically instead of `*`.

If this isn't fast enough for you and you control your server infrastructure, you may want to look into caching solutions like [Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php).

Answer (score 1):

That is as simple as youre going to get. This is not what you should be optimizing. It would be better if you optimize all processes leading to this query and after. This is at its optimum state.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need `crap` column then select only that column that will increase the speed than selecting all. Similarly select only those columns which you need. IF you need all then the query is in its fine state

Answer (score -1):

It should execute as fast as possible, they don't get simpler than this.